# Regex groups expression not capturing content

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to create a large regex expression where the plan is to capture 6 groups.
Is gonna be used to parse some Android log that have the following format:

```
2020-03-10T14:09:13.3250000 VERB    CallingClass    17503   20870   Whatever content: this log line had (etc)
```

The expression I've created so far is the following:

```regex
    (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{7})\t([A-Za-z]{4})\t(\w{+})\t(\d{5})\t(\d{5})\t(.*$)
```

The lines in this case are Tab separated, although the application that I'm developing will be dynamic to the point where this is not always the case, so regex I feel is still the best option even if heavier then performing a split.

Breaking down the groups in more detail from my though process:

1. Matches the date (I'm considering changing this to a x number of characters instead)

   (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{7})
2. Match a block of 4 characters

   ([A-Za-z]{4})
3. Match any number of characters until the next tab

   (\w{+})
4. Match a block of 5 numbers 2 times

   \t(\d{5})
5. At last, match everything else until the end of the line. 
   \t(.*$)

If I use a reduced expression to the following it works:

```regex
    (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{7})\t([A-Za-z]{4})\t(.*$)
```

This doesn't include 3 of the groups, the word and the 2 numbers blocks.

Any idea why is this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use regex? Couldn't you just use the positions within the string?

Comment: Are you reading a file with lines in this format? If so, you might be better off using CsvHelper and specifying tab as the separator.

Comment: Don't put + in curly braces `(\w+)`

Comment: Unfortunately it seems the tabs get lost in the formatting of the question.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich The positions are not always the same.

Comment: @madreflection It needs to be dynamic, I'm building a log parser that receives its definitions and file format by Json.

Comment: @juharr yes, that was the solution, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `\w{+}` is going to match a word character followed by one or more { characters and then a final } character.  If you want one or more word characters then just use plus without the curly braces (which are meant for specifying a specific number or number range, but will match literal curly braces if they do not adhere to that format).

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{7})\t([A-Za-z]{4})\t(\w+)\t(\d{5})\t(\d{5})\t(.*$)
```

I highly recommend using https://regex101.com/ for the explanation to see if your expression matches up with what you want spelled out in words.  However for testing for use in C# you should use something else like http://regexstorm.net/tester